# Using PTFE spray on rear derailleur springs

Tags: lubricant, derailleur-rear

Have noticed that the rear derailleur springs and pulleys are picking up lots of road gunk.  I use a wax for the chain and as this breaks off I can see it getting stuck on the pulleys.

So after cleaning out the chain and rear derailleur with citrus degreaser can you use PTFE spray, as in WD40 400ml High Performance PTFE Lubricant on the rear derailleur spring.  PTFE is basically teflon, but does it then over coat the spring and restrict movement ?

Comment: Not as desirable as a good chain lube.  If the lube is gunking up too fast you might switch to a "dry" lube that is heavy on the wax.  But neither is good if you frequently ride in the wet.

Comment: I realise that the question is slightly different, but in terms of the answers could this be a possible duplicate of [Spray new bike with teflon to repel dirt and moisture?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/spray-new-bike-with-teflon-to-repel-dirt-and-moisture)

Answer (score 2):

You most certainly *can* use a PTFE spray after cleaning, but, I would use a high quality chain lube instead.

I use this dry teflon lube on my drivetrain and use a precision applicator to lube my derailleurs after I clean the drivetrain.

Personally, I wouldn't use any WD40 branded lubricant on my bike.  Also, I'd recommend not using a spray type applicator to apply lubricant on small parts.  I like to use the precision applicator, i.e. the long, skinny straw, to be able to reach into all the pivots of the derailleurs and accurately apply the lube.  The spray can be messy and will often contaminate other parts of your bike, like rotors or brake tracks on your wheels.

The 'Dry' lube is nice because it doesn't pick up that much road grime in the derailleurs.

[image]

Comment: I agree that generally, spray bottles get lube in lots of places where it's not wanted because a spray nozzle by its nature covers an entire area.

Comment: Regarding WD40, they have new products sold under this brand that are specifically intended for bicycle applications. In the past, using WD40 on a bike was inappropriate, because they only had the "traditional" WD40, which is not a real lubricant.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the WD 40 spraying in unnecessary places, SPECIALLY the tyre's rubber gets damaged (used to get greyish braking debris like stains and sticky rubber on the sidewalls from any over spray)

However, as the last reply mentioned.

There are two new specific products from WD 40, that are lubricants and PTFE.

This line is called WD 40 Specialized.  I have the cheap wet version, really good! and have a long sprayer nozzle to direct to places (but still can over spray)

I just dislike bicycle specific brands for some reason.  Coming from an industrial background, I find majority are marketing gimmicks.   YES they are the best, but the price is really high.  Just like "ceramic" B.S ... You can buy the rolling ceramic elements for as low as 20$ and upgrade your hub bearings for example. rather than buying SHAMPAGNOLO HONOLULU ULTRA SUPER MEGA SLICK CERAMIC hubs and BB, for over $1000.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answers except the rant at the end, so I'm voting to delete.